# Converting word(.docx) to pdf using Apache POI and itext

Tags: java, itext, apache-poi, converters

In my java web application i have a **Persian** template word(docx) document as a contract that customize it for my users whit their data using **APACHE-POI** and after that i have to convert it to pdf in order to prevent the file from being distorted by the operator.
I tried to convert it using **itext** but i couldnt get success and couldnt find something helpful, can someone suggest a way for doing the conversion using itext or can anyone tell me if there is any other way to prevent the file from being distorted without doing conversion?

Edit note:I did the conversion whit the following codes below but now i have lots of question marks in my pdf file, can anyone help??does itext supports persian or RTL languages?how chan i solve this problem?
I am using version 5.0.6 of iText!!

```
convertWordToPdf("D:/PrivateBanking/docxCo.docx","D:/PrivateBanking/docxCo.pdf");

public static void convertWordToPdf(String src, String desc){
        try{
            //create file inputstream object to read data from file
            FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream(src);
            //create document object to wrap the file inputstream object
            XWPFDocument doc=new XWPFDocument(fs);
            //72 units=1 inch
            Document pdfdoc=new Document(PageSize.A4,72,72,72,72);
            //create a pdf writer object to write text to mypdf.pdf file
            PdfWriter pwriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfdoc, new FileOutputStream(desc));
            //specify the vertical space between the lines of text
            pwriter.setInitialLeading(20);
            //get all paragraphs from word docx
            List<XWPFParagraph> plist=doc.getParagraphs();

            //open pdf document for writing
            pdfdoc.open();
            for (int i = 0; i < plist.size(); i++) {
                //read through the list of paragraphs
                XWPFParagraph pa = plist.get(i);
                //get all run objects from each paragraph
                List<XWPFRun> runs = pa.getRuns();
                //read through the run objects
                for (int j = 0; j < runs.size(); j++) {
                    XWPFRun run=runs.get(j);
                    //get pictures from the run and add them to the pdf document
                    List<XWPFPicture> piclist=run.getEmbeddedPictures();
                    //traverse through the list and write each image to a file
                    Iterator<XWPFPicture> iterator=piclist.iterator();
                    while(iterator.hasNext()){
                        XWPFPicture pic=iterator.next();
                        XWPFPictureData picdata=pic.getPictureData();
                        byte[] bytepic=picdata.getData();
                        Image imag=Image.getInstance(bytepic);
                        pdfdoc.add(imag);

                    }
                    //get color code
                    int color=getCode(run.getColor());
                    //construct font object
                    Font f=null;
                    if(run.isBold() && run.isItalic())
                        f= FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,run.getFontSize(),Font.BOLDITALIC, new BaseColor(color));
                    else if(run.isBold())
                        f=FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,run.getFontSize(),Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(color));
                    else if(run.isItalic())
                        f=FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,run.getFontSize(),Font.ITALIC, new BaseColor(color));
                    else if(run.isStrike())
                        f=FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,run.getFontSize(),Font.STRIKETHRU, new BaseColor(color));
                    else
                        f=FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,run.getFontSize(),Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(color));
                    //construct unicode string
                    String text=run.getText(-1);
                    byte[] bs;
                    if (text!=null){
                        bs=text.getBytes();
                        String str=new String(bs,"UTF-8");
                        //add string to the pdf document
                        Chunk chObj1=new Chunk(str,f);
                        pdfdoc.add(chObj1);
                    }

                }
                //output new line
                pdfdoc.add(new Chunk(Chunk.NEWLINE));
            }
            //close pdf document
            pdfdoc.close();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

 public static int getCode(String code){
        int colorCode;
        if(code!=null)
            colorCode=Long.decode("0x"+code).intValue();
        else
            colorCode=Long.decode("0x000000").intValue();
        return colorCode;
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. For your attempt, you should check first if word doc is generating correctly and then if you have an error post it with the code involved. Is there another way? I guess you can set up document permissions or converting it into an image, these are my main ideas to solve your problem.

Comment: @RafaelPalomino hi rafael and thank you so much , i have checked and the word file generates correctly and now i get success in converting word to pdf but there is a one more problem that my file is Persian and i think iText doesnt support persian or RTL languages , and about converting to img , is this possible that coverts docx to png for example??

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse i have added my code.i did the conversion but all of the texts have turned to lots of question marks.does itext supports persian/arabic languages(also RTL)??

Comment: So now your question has changed. You have a pdf, but Persian text is not as expected.

Comment: Also missing: the version of iText you are using.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse exactly!!i have lots of question mark instead of my Persian texts.my itext version is 5.0.6

Comment: That is a very old version. I recommend using iText 7.1.3 instead. Also, Persian is a language with a complex writing system that makes use of ligatures (characters that are written differently when combined). For such advanced writing systems, you require the pdfCalligraph add-on. On the iText website you will find examples for Arabic and as far as understand it, while Persian and Arabic are totally different spoken languages, their writing system isn't too different. And finally, you also need to use a font that supports the characters in the Persian language.

Comment: (Yes, iText most definitely supports RTL languages).

Comment: @Sobhan It's possible in Itext5, check [How to create Persian content - IText5](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-persian-content-pdf), it should help. Topics like embedding of Persian font and text direction are covered there.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I added iText 7.1.3 in my application but my codes wont work anymore and most of the objects and classes that i had imported in my class are useless for example i cant find Font or i was using PageSize but now when i import the new PageSize i get error , what are the differences between iText5 and iText7?why i cant find some objects? , at the end could you please give me a link that there is an example of conversion from word to pdf?thanks a lot for your helps and the time you are spending for me

Comment: I am away on vacation and not spending any time. I hope someone else can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install MS Office before running, then:

```
import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType; 
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter; 
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import java.io.*; 
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future; 
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Converter{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("d:\\input.docx"));
        IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
                .baseFolder(new File("D:\\input"))
                .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        Future<Boolean> conversion = converter
                .convert(in).as(DocumentType.MS_WORD)
                .to(bo).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
                .schedule();
        conversion.get();
        try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\output.pdf")) {
            bo.writeTo(outputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        in.close();
        bo.close();
    }
}
```

These are the necessary maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-util-conversion</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-transformer</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-util-all</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-local</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-util-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: are you sure it will convert persian base word file to pdf??

Comment: Hi Mehran, thank you for taking the time to leave an answer :) Could you update it to include a description as to what you are doing?

Comment: @ I.T Delinquent     i cant customize it very much therefore i cant explain with detail    but it works for me:))

Comment: @mehranarbabian wont you answer my question??
does it conver persian language to pdf without changes on charecters???

Comment: @Sobhan yes i convert with it so many times    but be sure you installed ms office and select ms word as default

Comment: @mehranarbabian WELL DONE mehran, it worked for me too and really it converts persian word to pdf without any changes, thanks dude

Comment: does this still work? I tried to run it from ubuntu but got this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: class com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge could not be created by a (File, long, TimeUnit) constructor`

Comment: @Insane DA  it needs installing Microsoft word    sadly it works only on windows

Comment: @mehranarbabian
You should add this comment on the top:

but you have to install ms office before run

Comment: I have a similar use case. But I want to run this in a Linux server. But @Scott you have said that 'you need to install MS Office'. So does it mean that I can't run this code in a Linux machine?

Comment: @RohanSharma - This answer was actually from **mehranarbabian**, I just did some editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert docx to pdf using **APACHE-POI** then you will be needing following jars with suitable versions

```
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-x.x.x.jar
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-x.x.x.jar
```

If you want to using some other library then you can try **Docx4j**
You can find an example here: 
https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j

I hope this helps.

Comment: recently i have used APACHE-POI library for doing conversion but the converted file wasnt readable and i think it doesnt support Persian or RTL languages; the similar problem that now i have with itext after doing conversion.does DOCX4J supports persian(RTL) languages?

Comment: According to this link, from the version 3.1.0 it supports RTL languages(Arabic/Hebrew)
[link](https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/docx4j-3-1-0-released-t1874.html)